# Airflow does not trigger concurrent DAGs with `LocalExecutor`

Tags: python, airflow

I am using airflow 1.7.1.3.

I have an issue with concurrency DAGs / Tasks. When a DAG is running, the scheduler does not launch other DAGs any more. It seems that scheduler is totally frozen (no logs anymore) ... until the running DAG is finished. Then, the new DAGrun is triggered. My different tasks are long-running ECS task (~10 minutes)

I used `LocalExecutor` and I let default config about `parallelism=32` and `dag_concurrency=16`. I use `airflow scheduler -n 20` and reboot it automatically and I set `'depends_on_past': False` for all my DAGs declaration.

For information, I deployed airflow in containers running in an ECS cluster. `max_threads = 2` and I have only 2 CPU available.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue as well using the `LocalExecutor`. It seems to be a limitation in how the `LocalExecutor` works. The scheduler ends up spawning child processes (32 in your case). In addition, your scheduler performs 20 iterations per execution, so by the time it gets to the end of its 20 runs, it waits for its child processes to terminate before the scheduler can exit. If there is a long-running child process, the scheduler will be blocked on its execution.

For us, the resolution was to switch to the `CeleryExecutor`. Of course, this requires a bit more infrastructure, management, and overall complexity for the Celery backend.